# Adding Security to Firebase to prevent the insertion of additional data

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a field within Firebase called 'pending_members' which contains a list of members pending permission to be granted by an 'owner', as such, 'pending_members' requires the following rules:

1. The current user can only add themselves (uid)
2. The current user can remove only themselves (uid) from the list
3. The 'owner' can remove any member from the list
4. Only the 'owner' can read the list

I've tried various security rules but seem to miss many corner cases, for example, a user is given write access because the data contains their uid but they can then submit someone else's uid along with this.

Can anyone suggest appropriate rules for this situation? Many thanks

```
"pending_members" : {
    ".write" : "auth !== null && 
        // The user is authenticated AND
        (newData.child(auth.uid).exists() ||
        // The new data contains either the current user's id OR
        (!newData.exists() &&  
        // There's no new data (a delete operation) AND
        data === auth.uid))",
        // The old data is the current user's id

"$member" : {
    ".validate" : "newData.isString()",
        "$other": { ".write": false, ".read": false }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Structure Example:

```
users       ->
                personal_data   ->
                                    email                   (user email address)
                                    first_name              (user first name)
                                    last_name               (user last name)
                networks_index  ->
networks    ->
                members                 (list of uids of users linked to the network)
                owner                   (uid of the owner/primary user)
                pending_members         (list of uids of users wishing to link to the network)
```

[Data Example (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDtLi.png)

Comment: Can you add an example of the structure of your firebase?

Comment: @AndréKool added as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Complicated structure you have but i will give it a try:
Keep in mind standard value for read and write is false.

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "networks": {
      "$networkid": {
//Give read and write access to the owner of the network 
        ".read": "auth != null && "root.child('networks').child($networkid).child('owner').val() == auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && "root.child('networks').child($networkid).child('owner').val() == auth.uid",
        "pending_members": {
           "$uid": {
              //Give members write access to their own node inside pending_members
              ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
              //Use validate to check if the value is a bool or emty(removal)
              ".validate": newData.isBoolean() || !newData.exists()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have only concentrated on the pending_members here, I hope that is enough and it is clear enough. If it doesn't work i suggest testing each rule seperatly to see which one is causing a ploblem so I (or someone else) can help fix it.